R dplyr summarise over intervals
This is probably an R dplyr summarise question.
I have a data.frame with values recorded for subjects at 5 minute time intervals and it has these three columns: id: subject ID, value: the recorded value at the time point, and cum_time: the cumulative time value for each id:
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep("id1", 100), rep("id2", 100), rep("id3", 100)),
                 value = runif(300, 10, 20)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(cum_time = 5 * (dplyr::row_number()-1))

I'd like to compute a data.frame with the medians of value over 60 minute intervals to give this resulting data.frame:
rbind(data.frame(id = "id1", median_value = c(median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id1" & cum_time >= 0 & cum_time <= 60)$value),
                                              median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id1" & cum_time >= 65 & cum_time <= 120)$value),
                                              median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id1" & cum_time >= 125 & cum_time <= 180)$value),
                                              median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id1" & cum_time >= 185 & cum_time <= 240)$value),
                                              median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id1" & cum_time >= 245 & cum_time <= 300)$value)),
                 cum_time = c(60, 120, 180, 240, 300)),
      data.frame(id = "id2", median_value = c(median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id2" & cum_time >= 0 & cum_time <= 60)$value),
                                              median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id2" & cum_time >= 65 & cum_time <= 120)$value),
                                              median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id2" & cum_time >= 125 & cum_time <= 180)$value),
                                              median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id2" & cum_time >= 185 & cum_time <= 240)$value),
                                              median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id2" & cum_time >= 245 & cum_time <= 300)$value)),
                 cum_time = c(60, 120, 180, 240, 300)),
      data.frame(id = "id3", median_value = c(median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id3" & cum_time >= 0 & cum_time <= 60)$value),
                                              median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id3" & cum_time >= 65 & cum_time <= 120)$value),
                                              median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id3" & cum_time >= 125 & cum_time <= 180)$value),
                                              median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id3" & cum_time >= 185 & cum_time <= 240)$value),
                                              median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id3" & cum_time >= 245 & cum_time <= 300)$value)),
                 cum_time = c(60, 120, 180, 240, 300)))

    id median_value cum_time
1  id1     15.72853       60
2  id1     15.74687      120
3  id1     14.87811      180
4  id1     16.00048      240
5  id1     14.57858      300
6  id2     15.98761       60
7  id2     14.65317      120
8  id2     15.36035      180
9  id2     15.16835      240
10 id2     13.90954      300
11 id3     12.68951       60
12 id3     15.79852      120
13 id3     14.03968      180
14 id3     14.29187      240
15 id3     15.11250      300


Not exactly 60 minute interval if we are starting at 65 at the 2nd interval. If there wasn't a gap between the interval we could use cut()

Perhaps this approach works for you (with addition thanks to @thelatemail)?
df %>% 
  filter(cum_time<=300) %>% 
  group_by(id, grp=cut(cum_time, seq(0, max(cum_time),60), include.lowest = T)) %>% 
  summarize(median_value = median(value), cum_time=max(cum_time), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  select(-grp)

Output:
    id median_value cum_time
1  id1     15.72853       60
2  id1     15.74687      120
3  id1     14.87811      180
4  id1     16.00048      240
5  id1     14.57858      300
6  id2     15.98761       60
7  id2     14.65317      120
8  id2     15.36035      180
9  id2     15.16835      240
10 id2     13.90954      300
11 id3     12.68951       60
12 id3     15.79852      120
13 id3     14.03968      180
14 id3     14.29187      240
15 id3     15.11250      300


the provided interval is not continuous. the 2nd interval starts at 65 instead at 61. I suggest adding more cuts into the interval and then filtering them out before summarising

If you add cum_time = max(cum_time) to the summarise call you can even label it as requested.

Your desired interval goes like (0-60,65-120,125-180,...) which has gaps.
We can use cut() and since this function requires continuous intervals without gaps because you declare breaks of the intervals in cut(). So we will just have to remove the intervals that are the gaps not needed after.
foo = function(x){
  cut(x,breaks=c(-1,60,64,120,124,180,184,240,244,300),      
 labels=c("60","remove","120","remove","180","remove","240","remove","300"))
}

df |> 
  mutate(cum_interval=foo(cum_time))|>
  filter(cum_interval!="remove") |>
  group_by(id,cum_interval)|>
  summarise(median_value=median(value))



The inconsistent intervals is tricky; perhaps you could 'break it into two parts' then join the outcome? E.g.
Example data:
library(dplyr)
library(RcppRoll)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep("id1", 100), rep("id2", 100), rep("id3", 100)),
                 value = runif(300, 10, 20)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(cum_time = 5 * (dplyr::row_number()-1))

expected_outcome <- rbind(data.frame(id = "id1", median_value = c(median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id1" & cum_time >= 0 & cum_time <= 60)$value),
                                                                  median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id1" & cum_time >= 65 & cum_time <= 120)$value),
                                                                  median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id1" & cum_time >= 125 & cum_time <= 180)$value),
                                                                  median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id1" & cum_time >= 185 & cum_time <= 240)$value),
                                                                  median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id1" & cum_time >= 245 & cum_time <= 300)$value)),
                                     cum_time = c(60, 120, 180, 240, 300)),
                          data.frame(id = "id2", median_value = c(median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id2" & cum_time >= 0 & cum_time <= 60)$value),
                                                                  median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id2" & cum_time >= 65 & cum_time <= 120)$value),
                                                                  median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id2" & cum_time >= 125 & cum_time <= 180)$value),
                                                                  median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id2" & cum_time >= 185 & cum_time <= 240)$value),
                                                                  median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id2" & cum_time >= 245 & cum_time <= 300)$value)),
                                     cum_time = c(60, 120, 180, 240, 300)),
                          data.frame(id = "id3", median_value = c(median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id3" & cum_time >= 0 & cum_time <= 60)$value),
                                                                  median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id3" & cum_time >= 65 & cum_time <= 120)$value),
                                                                  median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id3" & cum_time >= 125 & cum_time <= 180)$value),
                                                                  median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id3" & cum_time >= 185 & cum_time <= 240)$value),
                                                                  median(dplyr::filter(df, id == "id3" & cum_time >= 245 & cum_time <= 300)$value)),
                                     cum_time = c(60, 120, 180, 240, 300)))

Example code:
first_block <- df %>%
  filter(cum_time <= 60) %>%
  mutate(median_value = median(value)) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  filter(cum_time == 60)

second_time_block <- df %>%
  filter(cum_time >= 65) %>%
  mutate(median_value = roll_median(value, n = 12, by = 12, fill = NA,
                                    align = c("right"))) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  filter(cum_time %% 60 == 0)

outcome <- first_block %>%
  bind_rows(second_time_block) %>%
  arrange(cum_time, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  filter(cum_time <= 300)

all_equal(expected_outcome, outcome)
#> [1] TRUE

Created on 2024-05-17 with reprex v2.1.0
